# Can a wicket:child tag be nested under another Component on the Page?

Tags: html, css, wicket

In Wicket 1.4, I'm trying to allow child pages to alter a CSS class on a tag in the parent page, which I do all the time.  What is odd about this case is that the tag I want to target **wraps the child page markup**.  Here's a simplified snip of what I tried:

ParentPage.html

```
<div id="main" wicket:id="main">
  <wicket:child />
</div>
```

ParentPage.java

```
public abstract class ParentPage {

  private WebMarkupContainer main;

  protected ParentPage() {
    main = new WebMarkupContainer("main");
    add(main);
  }

  public void setClassAttr(String cssClass){
    main.add(SimpleAttributeModifier("class", cssClass);
  }
}
```

ChildPage.html

```
<wicket:extend>
  ...
</wicket:extend>
```

ChildPage.java

```
public class ChildPage extends Page {    
   ...

    public ChildPage() {
      super();
      ...     
      setClassAttr("specific-class-for-this-page");
    }
}
```

...Which blows up because it appears the HTML from the *child* loads, but not the java.  (If I remove the wicket:id and java code on `div#main`, all is well.)

Note that the tag on the *parent* that I want to manipulate *from the child* is actually wrapping the `wicket:child` tag.  In other cases I have done something similar, the tags I want to monkey with tend to be siblings or otherwise distant to the `wicket:child` tag.

All I really want to do is allow the child to change the class attribute on the parent - is there another way to do this?  Why can't a child page be nested under another Wicket page component?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. If you're using `<wicket:child>`, you should have at least two component (or page) classes, one extending the other.

Comment: Sorry, I ommitted that detail originally but have now added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it has nothing to do with actually setting the attribute, but with putting `<wicket:child>` inside a container.

Now imagine if `ChildPage` was a `Panel`, what would the code of your `ParentPage` look like? It would contain a line somewhere saying `main.add( new ChildPanel() )`. That's how the `main` component knows that when it renders, it should call the rendering method of your child panel too.

But with inheritance it's different. Your `main` component has no way of knowing what `<wicket:child>` should resolve to. Marking your `main` container transparent tells Wicket to ask the parent component (that is, your page component) to resolve and render it.

Answer (score 7):

I would just like to point out that this has been removed as of Wicket 1.5. So, if you are using Wicket 1.5 or higher, you would use a `TransparentWebMarkupContainer` component instead of `WebMarkupContainer.isTansparentResolver()`. I also had the same problem as the poster. I have an outer, containing div which wraps a wicket:child tag, and I adjust its width (Twitter Bootstrap fluid grid) based on the content that it needs to display. My `mainContentContainer` is a `TransparentWebMarkupContainer`:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" wicket:id="sidebarPanel"></div>
    <div class="span6" wicket:id="mainContentContainer">
        <wicket:child/>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" wicket:id="rightPanel"></div>
</div>
```

Sometimes the `rightPanel` is completely hidden, and the `mainContentContainer` changes to `class="span9"` to take up the unused viewport.

[See here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-MarkupContainer.isTransparentResolver%2528%2529removed).

*Thanks for posting. I had the exact same problem until I read this post.*

Answer (score 1):

it's working great. on the component where is wicket:id="main" do what is above.

```
ain = new WebMarkupContainer("main") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean isTransparentResolver() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

and exception do not occur.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your childpage extends the parentpage. Why not pass the class name into the parent's constructor like

```
public class ChildPage extends ParentPage {    
   public ChildPage() {
     super("my-class");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker found the fix - make the component about the wicket:child tag a "transparentResolver".  +1 to anyone who can clearly articulate how this works precisely?

```
    main = new WebMarkupContainer("main") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public boolean isTransparentResolver() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    add(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your wicket usage (or at least code you posted) is strange (I tried with 1.4.22)...

```
public abstract class ParentPage {
```

Probably you forgot `extends WebPage`.

```
public class ChildPage extends Page {
```

here you want to extends `ParentPage` I guess.

Everything works as expected and final HTML generated is

```
<div id="main" wicket:id="main" class="specific-class-for-this-page">
    <wicket:child>
        <wicket:extend>
            text
        </wicket:extend>
    </wicket:child>
</div>
```

My recommendation is "do not use HTML id for wicket elements when you do not need to".