# Wicket markup inheritance not working for wicket:child tags within MarkupContainers

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using [markup inheritance](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html#layout_4) in Wicket 6.14.0 to create a simple widget with title and content. The parent's markup looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket>
<wicket:panel>
<div wicket:id="widgetBox">
  <div wicket:id="widgetTitle"><wicket:enclosure child="icon"><span class="icon"><i wicket:id="icon"></i></span></wicket:enclosure>
    <h5 wicket:id="headline"></h5>
  </div>
  <div wicket:id="widgetContent"><wicket:child/></div>
</div>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

Its code is pretty straight-forward, but for the sake of completeness:

```
public class ParentPanel extends Panel {

        public ParentPanel(final String id, final IModel<String> title) {
            super(id, title);       

            WebMarkupContainer widgetBox = new WebMarkupContainer("widgetBox");         
            add(widgetBox);

            final WebMarkupContainer widgetTitle = new WebMarkupContainer("widgetTitle");           
            widgetBox.add(widgetTitle);

            final WebMarkupContainer icon = new WebMarkupContainer("icon");
            if (titleIcon != null) {
                // custom class
                icon.add(new IconBehavior("titleIcon"));
            } else {
                icon.setVisible(false);
            }
            widgetTitle.add(icon);
            widgetTitle.add(new Label("headline", title));

            widgetContent = new WebMarkupContainer("widgetContent");
            widgetContent.add(new WidgetContentBehavior());
            widgetBox.add(widgetContent);
        }
}
```

Now for the child component. Here's its most simple markup:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket>
<wicket:extend>
  <span wicket:id="foobar"></span>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

And of course the Java code:

```
public class ChildPanel extends ParentPanel {

    public ChildPanel(final String id, final IModel<String> title) {
        super(id, title);
        add(new Label("foobar", "Foobar"));
    }

}
```

What I'm expecting of course is a rendered page saying "Foobar" where the wicket:child tag is placed. Instead there's this RuntimeException:

```
Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'foobar' in [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_extend3]]
    Expected: 'foobar:widgetBox:widgetContent:wicket_child2:wicket_extend3:foobar'.
    Found with similar names: 'foobar', foobar:foobar'
```

It seems as if markup inheritance does not support wicket:child tags within a MarkupContainer and therefore messes up the hierarchy. I also considered using a [Border](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Border) instead, getting the same outcome though.

My question of course is how to get this work by maintaining the current hierarchy, as it's important to have control (read: a Java Object) of widgetBox and widgetContent.

Comment: Without testing (can't test right now) I'd say, since the child-tag is withing your WebMarkupContainer so are it's contents. That way you can't just add your Label to the Panel but have to add it to your widgetContent object.

Comment: @Nicktar that's something I've tried as a workaround before posting the question, it just leads to a slightly different path in the same exception, as it still expects the component of the child to be after the :wicket_extend3:. Also it'd be against the idea of markup inheritance if I'd have to be aware of the parent's hierarchy.

Comment: @Nicktar but you're of course right. I could make it work using a Border now, I'll provide an answer later.

Comment: I think you can use TransparentWebMarkupContainer (instead of a "regular" one). "Transparent" means, that it is not interfering with the component hierarchy (you are adding the label "foobar" directly to the page and not to the WebMarkupContainer).

Comment: @mrak using TransparentWebMarkupContainer for both widgetBox and widgetContent indeed solves the problem. Please add as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another question regarding your issue:
[Can a wicket:child tag be nested under another Component on the Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068142/can-a-wicketchild-tag-be-nested-under-another-component-on-the-page)

The answers provided use `TransparentWebMarkupContainer` to solve the issue.

**However**, as I found out, note that using `TransparentWebMarkupContainer` will fail if your child page defines `wicket:fragment`s. See issues [WICKET-4545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545) and [WICKET-5440](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545)

Comment: You sure? Affects Version/s: 1.5.6, OP is using 6.14.0. Besides OP is not using TransparentWebMarkupContainer - this may be the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with 6.12.0 (see my duplicate issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5440) so I'm pretty confident :) But you're right that the original issue is regarding the 1.5 branch.